# Having trouble with joint probability distribution

Tags: probability

> A pair of 6-sided dice is thrown once.  One die is red and the other d 
>       die is black.  Let $X$ represent the outcome of the red die and let $Y$ 
>       equal the absolute value of the difference of the outcomes of the two 
>       dice.  Write the joint probability distribution of $X$ and $Y$.
>       How would I approach this type of problem?

What I do know is that there are $6 \cdot 6 = 36$ outcomes.

I drew a $6\times 6$ grid and tried labelling all the possible outcomes followed by the number of times they occur, but I feel like I got no where.  I know approach is very wrong.

What's the correct approach?

Comment: Just enumerate and count, I'm not sure a compact closed form exists.

Comment: Can you show us your table, like this (copied from the MathJax tutorial): \begin{array}{c|cccc}
\Delta&0&1&2&3\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
3 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0
\end{array}

Answer (score 1):

> I drew a 6x6 grid and tried labeling all the possible outcomes followed by the number of times they occur, but I feel like I got no where. I know approach is very wrong.

The approach is correct.  The table should look as follows, just complete it.

$$\begin{array}{:c|c:c:c:c:c:c:}\hline \lower{1ex}X\backslash Y & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\\hline 1& 1/36& 1/36& 1/36& 1/36& 1/36& 1/36 \\ \hdashline 2 & 1/36 & 2/36 & 1/36& 1/36& 1/36 & 0 \\ \hdashline 3 & \\ \hdashline 4\\ \hdashline 5\\ \hdashline 6 \\ \hline\end{array}$$

Or perhaps start off by listing outcomes of the die rolls that lead to each pair of results.

$$\begin{array}{:c|c:c:c:c:c:c:}\hline \lower{1ex}X\backslash Y & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\\hline 1& (1,1)& (1,2)& (1,3)& (1,4)& (1,5)& (1,6) \\ \hdashline 2 & (2,2) & {(2,1),\\(2,3)} & (2,4)& (2,5)& (2,6) & \{\} \\ \hdashline 3 & \\ \hdashline 4\\ \hdashline 5\\ \hdashline 6 \\ \hline\end{array}$$

Comment: nice table, just move $1/36$ factor out to eliminate visual clutter.

Comment: ah I think I get it.  1/36, 2/36, 3/6, 4/6, 5/6, 6/6 should be all written diagonally followed 1/36 everywhere right?

Comment: Not at all, @obsolutemal .  Think about how many dice outcomes, for example, lead to $X=3, Y=2$.

Comment: still feel kinda lost :o

Answer (score 0):

- Your approach seems correct. Let the rows of the table correspond to the 6 outcomes on the black die, and let the columns of the table correspond to the 6 outcomes on the red die.
- For entry in the table, you can fill in the value of $X$ (outcome of the red die) and the value of $Y$ (absolute difference between red and black) corresponding to that entry.
- The joint probability distribution on $X$ and $Y$ is the probability of getting any particular $\langle x,y\rangle$ pair.
- Because each entry in the table is equally likely (1/36), the probability of a particular $\langle x,y\rangle$ pair is equal to the number of times it occurs in this table, multiplied by 1/36.

Answer (score 0):

Let's work on $X=3$ case, the other dice will take values $\{1..6\}$, where the corresponding $Y$ values will be $\{2,1,0,1,2,3\}$ Grouping the same values together will give (value, count) pairs as $\{(0,1), (1,2), (2,2), (3,1)\}$.  Converting this the probability, you'll need to divide each count by $6*6$.

Note that due to symmetry $P(X,Y)=P(6-X+1,Y)$, so you just need to do this for $1$ and $2$, but $1$ is already the trivial case.